# Why am getting an "elif" syntax error showing invalid syntax in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Whts wrong in this statement??
and why am getting this error.

```
a = 200
b = 33
c = 500
if a < b:
  print("Both conditions are True")
  elif a>b and True :
  print("f")
```

Error:

```
elif a>b and True :
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Move `elif` out of the `if` block

Comment: Move `elif` 2 spaces back, it should have same indentation as `if`.

Comment: What's the point of `and True`?

Comment: `if a < b:
  print("Both conditions are True")
   elif a>b and True :
   print("f") `     Still getting error @andnik

Comment: @PrashantepicProgrammer You had an indentation error. It's impossible to tell if you fixed that based on code in a comment.

Comment: `and True` was just for testing purpose!! @Fred Larson

Comment: @PrashantepicProgrammer, like what Prachiti Prakash Prabhu wrote in here answer. This's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

The identation is incorrect and causing the error. Also, the `and true` does not serve anything there. You can try the following code:

```
a = 200
b = 33
c = 500
if a < b:
  print("Both conditions are True")
elif a > b:
  print("f")
```

Comment: `and True` wasn't part of the syntax error, though it is almost certainly a logic error.

Comment: @chepner agreed! Modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

`elif` goes on the same level of indentation as `if`. It's *after* the `if` statement, not *inside* it:

```
if a < b:
  print("Both conditions are True")
elif a>b and True :
  print("f")
```